# Matplotlib 3d background always on top

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to introduce a matplotlib Slider in my 3d plot for some real-time interaction...

The thing is, as I move the slider around, the background lines on the 3d surface keep rendering on top. Increasing the `zorder` over 9000 doesn't help either, and I've tried working around the problem for a while now, to no avail.

The code is as follows, see for yourself:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

K = 1.0

def calculate_and_plot():
    X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
    Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    Z = np.sin(K*R)
    ax.cla()
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False, zorder=9001)

#Default plot
calculate_and_plot()

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axs  = plt.axes([0.02,0.02, 0.7, 0.05], axisbg=axcolor)
samp = Slider(axs, 'K', 0.2, 5.0, valinit=1.0)

def update(val):
    global K
    K = samp.val
    calculate_and_plot()
    plt.draw()
samp.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Any ideas?

-EDIT:

So I found a temporary and easy workaround this bug, I just call `surf.remove()` instead of `ax.cla()` before plotting an updated surface (with care to plot the first surface separetely, outside `calculate_and_plot()`, so we can keep a global reference to `surf`). Maybe it was meant to be done this way in any case...

Comment: It's the `ax.cla()` that is the culprit ... it looks fine if you take that out (of course then you overlap all your plots).  The slider doesn't appear to have anything to do with it, I reproduced the results in a linear script just by clearing the axes before the first plot.  It may be a bug ... perhaps ask the devs about it?

Comment: It is indeed a bug, apparently still not fixed: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/750
Thanks for suggesting it! (we always assume the problem to be in our code, yet sometimes...)